# DevExpress LookupEdit issue

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, lookup

My DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit control is not working

I Fill the combo with this code:

```
void FillCombo() 
{
     cboStep.Properties.DataSource = ProceduresDALC.Fill_StepDetail(" Where StepID = "+_StepID);
     cboStep.Properties.DisplayMember = "Description";
     cboStep.Properties.ValueMember = "StepID";
     cboStep.Properties.Columns.Clear();
     cboStep.Properties.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Description", "Step Detail"));
 }
```

The values are loaded into LookUpEdit

But when I choose a value from the LookUpEdit it gives me the first value only instead of my preferred value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure that StepID is a primary key here. If it isnt a primary key then it will give you the first value on change index event

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly to me with my datasource:

```
void FillLookUp() {
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = new List<StepDetails>{
        new StepDetails(){ StepID = 0, Description = "Step1" },
        new StepDetails(){ StepID = 1, Description = "Step2" },
        new StepDetails(){ StepID = 2, Description = "Step3" },
    };
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Description";
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "StepID";
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.Columns.Clear();
    lookUpEdit1.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("Description", "Step Detail"));
}
```

It seems that some problems with retrieving data from your database cause this issue.
So, I suggest you contact the [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) for further research.